# Como fazer a predição de vários modelos estatísticos gerados no R no Power BI?

Tags: r, machine-learning, powerbi

Treinei vários modelos no R, como estes:

```
iris2 <- data.frame(zzz= sample(c(0, 1),size =  length(iris$Sepal.Length), replace = TRUE), iris)
for (i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  saveRDS(glm(zzz ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data =  iris2[iris2$Species == i,]),
  file = paste0("model_", i))
}
```

Agora preciso colocar estes **RDS** no Power BI para para realizar o `predict()` em um script dentro do PB, entretanto o PB não aceita listas.

Não tive sucesso com a solução: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-predict-values-from-a-custom-r-model-in-power-bi-3364f83b0015